# Displaying date underscore template

Tags: c#, underscore.js

I am using underscore template and want to display Date format.

```
importHistories = new List<object>();
importHistories.AddRange(context.Imports.Select(t =>
 new
  {
      DateCreated = t.DateCreated,
      ImportHistoryId = t.ImportHistoryId,
```

Underscore template

```
<% _.each(ImportHistories, function(history) { %>
 <tr>
     <td><%=history.ImportHistoryId %></td>
     <td><%=history.DateCreated %></td>
 </tr>
<% });%>
```

as it is the date is displayed as such

```
/Date(1386682653060)/
```

How could I apply formtting to the date in the template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it.

Made the following change

```
importHistories.AddRange(context.Imports.ToList().Select(t =>
new
{
     DateCreated = t.DateCreated.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"),
     ImportHistoryId = t.ImportHistoryId,
```